# ASP Date Comparison

Tags: asp-classic, operators, date

Here is the code.

```
<%

expire_date = Session("expiration_date")
current_date = date()

If current_date >= expire_date Then
response.Redirect("../login_expiration.asp")
Else
' do nothing
End If

%>
```

Assuming the expiration date is 7/10/2011, what should happen?  I expect the redirect to happen, but the opposite does.  If I change the operator to "<=", the redirect happens.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Brett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to cast Session("expiration_date") from a string to a date:

`expire_date = CDate(Session("expiration_date"))`